# Display tables from SQL in DataGridView

Tags: c#

I created a DataBase named *charityah* containing 5 tables. Their names are listed in a combobox.

When I choose one of them I want to display their content in a DataGridView.

What I tried is: first I linked the DataGridView to this database and tried this code that I found:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = comboBox1.Text;

    connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Downloads\charityah.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    using (connection)
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from "+s, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, s);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Refresh();   
    }
}
```

This method doesn't give me any errors and it finds the tables, but nothing is seen in the DataGridView.

Comment: What does `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` report after the `Fill(ds,s)` ?

Comment: also: I wonder how much of this is related to you *disposing* (in the event-handler) an object that exists longer than that (as a field). You have a single `connection` instance, which you `Dispose()` (via `using`) every time it is used... it is guaranteed to not work the second time... (Personally, I would fix that by removing the field, and moving the `new Connection()` into the method, i.e. `using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cs)) {...}`

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count gave me the number of rows that exist..

Comment: i didn't understand the last thing you said but i put
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
inside the methode and i used instead of using(connection) connection.open() and connection.close()

Comment: you only need to dispose something once; once you've done that *it is toast*. By using `using` on a field, you've doomed the object at `connection` to be useless after the first time through that event handler. You can open/close things lots of times - but disposal is pretty fatal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you report (comments) that there are rows, it sounds like the primary problem (connection disposal aside) is an issue with data-binding. A few thoughts leap to mind:

- is the table in virtual mode?
- is it adding columns?
- do the columns already exist?

You might want to try adding:

```
dataGridView1.VirtualMode = false;
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

before the:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

You might also want to check that `dataGridView1.DataMember` doesn't have a value assigned.

Comment: ty so much :D
this problem made me a headache :P

Answer (score 0):

try this, some times nonsense items do create a lot of mess. so try setting autogenerate columns to true. may this starts showing you the results. because as per your comments, it dosent seems there could be any other issue. so just give it a try
     dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;